# How to get a Box2D Polygon's coordinates?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a body with just one fixture attached to it. The shape attached to the fixture is a PolygonShape. For rendering the body, I need access to its vertices' coordinates.

This is what I tried:

```
Vector2 tmpVector = new Vector2();
Fixture f = body.getFixtureList().get(0);
PolygonShape shape = (PolygonShape)f.getShape();
shape.getVertex(3, tmpVector);
shape.getVertex(2, tmpVector);
shape.getVertex(1, tmpVector);
shape.getVertex(0, tmpVector);
```

It works when the body is not in contact with other bodies.

The problem is that when the body collides with another body, `getFixtureList` returns more than one fixture and this includes those from other bodies.

How do I solve this problem?

All I need to be able to do is access the vertices' positions of the polygon body on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the fixture's body is equal to `body` with the `getBody()` method:

```
Vector2 tmpVector = new Vector2();
Fixture f = body.getFixtureList().get(0);
while (f.getBody() != body)
{
    f = f.getNext();
}
if (f != null)
{
    PolygonShape shape = (PolygonShape)f.getShape();
    // get vertices
}
```

Of course this work only if you know that `body` has exactly one fixture with a polygon shape, as it is said in the question. Otherwise you might consider using the `userData` attribute to store information about the different fixtures.

Comment: thanks. but is this the right way of getting a polygon body's coordinates?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Java port of Box2D, and in C++ `getFIxtureList` never returns a fixture that is not attached to the body. I know this piece of code may look like a trick, but it works, and if what you say is true I think these are the two only ways to get the proper fixture.